# tcolorbox not loading

Tags: tcolorbox

I'm actually not sure if it's a loading or compiling issue.  The package `tcolorbox` itself seems to load, together with its inclusions `pgf`, `verbatim`, `etoolbox`, and `environ`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

Hello World!

\end{document}
```

However, this package call results in 39 errors, the first two of which are:

```
pdflatex> ! Undefined control sequence.
pdflatex> 1.137 \ExplSyntaxOn
pdflatex> ! Undefined control sequence.
pdflatex> 1.141 \ExplSyntaxOff
```

There's also:

```
pdflatex> ! Undefined control sequence.
pdflatex> 1.2161 \NewDocumentCommand
pdflatex> {\tcblistof}{ O{\section} m o m }
```

and later:

```
pdflatex> ! LaTeX Error:  Missing \begin{document}.
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: The mini document compiles fine for me. What version of pdflatex are you using? (`pdflatex -v`) Can you post the entire log file somewhere?

Comment: @frabjous I attempted to update my `pgf` package using the package manager, but things didn't go well, and now I fear I've messed up my system.  I'm running Miktex 2.9, which doesn't seem to have a so-called Miktek-Console.  I don't know where I would post a log file.  What would you recommend at this point?

Comment: I don't think it's the `pgf` package that needs updating, but `pdflatex` itself. Some of those commands were added to the kernel around 2019/2020, and MikTeX 2.9 is from 2017. Uninstall MikTeX 2.9 and install the current version (which will hopefully fix your messed up system), or switch to another TeX distribution. That's my best guess anyway. You could post the log file at pastebin.com or gists.github.com similar.

Comment: @frabjous I think my system is back in order now, but I definitely need to update MiKTeX.  Can I install the current version alongside my old version, just in case things go badly, or might that cause conflicts?

Comment: Sorry I'm a TeXlive user, not a MikTeX user, so I don't really know. If you don't still need the old one, I'd take the risk of getting rid of it, but maybe a MikTeX user who knows more will come along and answer.